# How to load widgetkit shortcode in modules?

Tags: joomla, shortcode

i look for a way to load widgetkit in any module. For example in mod_content. I dont want to use default joomla! {loadposition #} to load another widgetkit module in mod_content.

I think that is more straightforward to user widgetkit shortcode in module. this doesnt work on some sites. On some sites it works.

Has anyone an idea how to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the "Prepare Content" option in basic configuration of the module is enabled. However you might want to use a widgetkit module *and* a content module to keep things separate.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the shortcode of the widget...e.g. [widgetkit id=4].. then select yes in the prepare content in the basic options of the custom html module.